# Trying to download eclipse on new computer. Error JRE missing, can't open file

Tags: installation, java, eclipse, jre

Java is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_201

When I try to run the eclipse download (https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) the browser in the picture pops up. The fixes I have come across deal with the error 'no JRE' once you have downloaded eclipse and have the eclipse folder. Currently there is no eclipse folder, so I can't even try the fixes I found.

[image: Error message in browser]

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a JRE.

I googled for "JRE Missing" and got to this website:

https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/index-handler.php

There I clicked on Oracle JRE 8 and got to this website:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

In the table "Java SE Runtime Environment 8u202" I clicked on "Windows x64  73.7 MB jre-8u202-windows-x64.exe" (the second last option).

After downloading that, I was able to start the eclipse download.

Hope it´ll also help you (if you still need it).